# Matplotlib animate - empty axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, animation

I want to do a simple [matplotlib animation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html#matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation) plot in the Jupyter Notebook using the following code:

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
import matplotlib.animation as animation


X,y_train = make_classification(n_samples=100,n_features=2,n_informative=2,n_redundant=0,n_clusters_per_class =1,shift=0,class_sep=1.9) 

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)


def update(num,X,y_train):
    ax.scatter(X[:num,0],X[:num,1])



ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,update,frames=10,interval=1000,fargs=[X,y_train])
plt.show()
```

But I do not receive any plot... Just an empty figure like:
[image]

I have also tried without $matplotlib inline but it is still not working.
Can anybody help me please?

Comment: how you tried removing the plt.show() ?  From my Udemy course I recall the instructor saying thats only needed for outside of jn.

Comment: You cannot use the `%matplotlib inline` backend for interactive plots.